# What Webcam is Compatible with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, webcam, logitech

I am working on a project of mine which requires a webcam and MATLAB. I have a Logitech Webcam, and I dont know if I could talk to it through MATLAB because Im trying to work with images and image processing, so I just want to know if there is a way to find out if the webcam is combatible with matlab or if I need to get some other type of webcam to get the job done, if I do need to get another one, it would be helpful if you suggest a certain cam that is cheap and available around.
Thank you.

Comment: Found some links that may be helpful: http://makarandtapaswi.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/webcam-capture-in-matlab/ & http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22792-video-tutorial-how-to-connect-a-webcam-with-matlab

Answer (score 2):

I've used several Logitech webcams with the Image Acquisition Toolbox on Windows. You'll find a list of supported hardware [here](http://www.mathworks.com/products/imaq/supportedioWindows.html).